# How to create a matrix 3x3 from a text file

Tags: java, matrix, jcreator

I  have to create a 3x3 matrix from a txt file and then get the determinant.
I tried to do it with these numbers:

```
22 10 15
12 5 8
22 3 8
```

But when I run the program the matrix is:

```
22 10 15 
12 5 88 
22 3 8
```

Comment: Can you post your code? (Please [edit] your question with the code)

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Or how do you expect us to help you with your problem without you disclosing the code creating the problem?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of responsiveness. Dropping a question to then walk away and not being around to react to feedback is not appreciated.

Comment: Is the `88` a typo?

Answer (score -1):

Umm.. not sure what exactly do you expect

```
    int [] matrix = new int [9];

    File file = newFile("filepath")

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) 
    {
        String line;
        int i=0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String [] numbers=line.split(" ");

            for(int j=0;j<numbers.length;j++)
            {
                if(numbers[j].matches(("-?\\d+")))
                {
                   matrix[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);
                   i++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("determinant: "+ Integer.toString(matrix[0]*matrix[4]*matrix[8] + matrix[1]*matrix[5]*matrix[6] + matrix[2]*matrix[3]*matrix[7]));
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is an example how can you calculate determinant

Comment: The question looks a lot like homework, and as written is too broad. Whilst this is an answer, SO really shouldn't be a code writing service, and you are encouraging these types of questions by responding in full.